# First option element wont work unless I select another option and then the first option will work

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, asynchronous, tailwind-css

I have a select element that fetches a .json file from my local project folder that's stored into an array called "Books" = [
{
"filename": "Genesis.json"
"title": "Genesis"
}
].

The for loop that populates my book and the chapters will populate the 0th index, however it wont allow me to select it.

```
/**
 * List of books in an array and its order
 * @typedef {{
 *   book: string,
 *   chapters: {
 *     chapter: string,
 *     verses: {
 *       verse: string,
 *       text: string,
 *     }[],
 *   }[],
 * }} Book
 *
 * Loads a book based on its filename (e.g. "Luke.json")
 * @param {string} filename The book filename
 * @returns {Promise<Book>} The book that was read from JSON
 */

bookSelector.onchange = () => {
  const filename = bookSelector.value;
  selectBookByFileName(filename);
};

chapterSelector.onchange = () => {
  const container0 = document.getElementById("verseContainer0");
  const container1 = document.getElementById("verseContainer1");

  if (currentBook == null) {
    return;
  }

  container0.innerText = "";
  container1.innerText = "";

  const chapter = currentBook.chapters[chapterSelector.value];
  const verses = chapter.verses;

  function createElementForVerse(verse) {
    const superscript = document.createElement("sup");
    const textElem = document.createElement("span");

    superscript.innerText = verse.verse;
    textElem.appendChild(superscript);
    superscript.classList.add("mr-1");

    textElem.classList.add("p-1");
    textElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(verse.text));

    return textElem;
  }

  for (const verse of verses) {
    // Append to both containers
    container0.appendChild(createElementForVerse(verse));
    container1.appendChild(createElementForVerse(verse));
  }

  document.getElementById("verseBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    container0.classList.toggle("grid");
    container1.classList.toggle("grid");
  });
};
```

Comment: possibly because you `selectBookByFileName(filename);` only on change - after you populate the books, do what you do in `bookSelector.onchange` if you've selected a book when populating

Comment: Share your code for `selectBookByFileName`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon async function selectBookByFileName(fileName) {
  const book = await loadBook(fileName);

  currentBook = book;

  // Clear existing chapters
  chapterSelector.innerText = "";

  // Populate chapterNumbers
  for (let i = 0; i < book.chapters.length; i++) {
    const chapter = book.chapters[i];

    const optionChapt = document.createElement("option");

    optionChapt.innerText = chapter.chapter;
    optionChapt.value = i;

    chapterSelector.appendChild(optionChapt);
  }
}

Comment: Do not add code in the comment section